# Break span to newline(s) instead of crossing or pushing right float divs?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

How can I push the text of a span (which starts at a variable left position) to a newline so that it respects the space of a set of fixed right floated divs?

I'd need to make sure that the `span` with the text "THIS ONE NEEDS TO BREAK..." breaks to a newline instead of pushing the fixed width divs right of it to the next row.
Since this is inside a tree, the `left` of the spans is variable, the deeper inside the hierarchy, the less the total width.

The solution has to work for IE8.

The HTML:

```
<li>
    <div>+</div>
    <div class="icon">
        <span class="nodetext">THIS ONE NEEDS TO BREAK BEFORE NEXT SPAN (Orange line)</span>
        <span class='tree'>
             <div>FIXED</div>
             <div>40px</div>
             <div>FOR</div>
             <div>THESE</div>
        </span>
    </div>
</li>
```

The CSS:

```
.tree
{   
    position:relative;
    float:right;
}

.tree div
{
   float: left;
   width: 40px;
}

span.nodetext
{
    /* 
       How to respect the orange line boundary?
    */
}
```

One image is...
[image]

I also made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzAba/1/).
This is the incorrect behavior: Only if the right column (with "Result" and "CSS") is wide enough is the display correct. If the right column is too small then the result is all messed up. (the CSS is also not 100% correct in the fiddle: the orange line is not fixed due to margins/paddings - which I added in an attempt to make it clearer what is what)

Comment: Then why don't you set a width to the "span.nodetext" elements?

Comment: The width depends on where we are in the tree.

Comment: Then try adding an outer div for each "span.nodetext" and give the width to it.

Comment: Basically we are nesting `ul>li`. The `span.nodetext` is a descendant of the `li`. We don't know the width of the `li` since it depends how deep it is nested. If the starting width is 500px then the span.nodetext width is: `(500px - #amount of parent uls# * indent-width)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to say it... but this is better to do in a table.  Unless you want to use jQuery to jump down a DIV, get the width, and put it on the span up above.  Or you can start thinking of it in terms of making your DIV's columns instead of rows.